# Tracking Conversions with Facebook Conversion Pixel

Tags: facebook

Facebook recommends including their tracking pixel in the head section:

```
<head>
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
  <script>
     ... code ...
     fbq('init', 'XXXXX');
     fbq('track', "PageView");
     ... more code
 </script>
  <!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
</head>
```

But I also want to track conversions. Do I add `fbq('track', 'CompleteRegistration');` in the original pixel code in the head? Or do I fire it only on the pages where the user is converted? (e.g. "Thank You" page)

If I just include it in the head, how does FB know what a "Complete Registration" is?

Comment: Facebook will not know what a “complete registration” is. But if you have a page that the user only gets to see after their registration, then you can put the code into the head of that page, so that it will track only then.

Answer (score 1):

Once the user successfully completes the registration, you need to fire this

`fbq('track', 'CompleteRegistration');`